# How do I dump a remote MySQL database using Java?

Tags: java, mysql, remote-server

I've seen this work with local MySQL databases:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD DBNAME > /path/to/location/backup.sql");
```

But is it possible to dump a remote MySQL database from a web server?

I'm making a program that backs up both my website files via FTP (already done with this part), and backs up my MySQL databases on the server as well. Therefore I need to know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to dump your database data from other computer you'll need to grand privileges to an specific user for this task.

for example, the user is: 'remoteAdminUser'

```
GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES 
ON *.* 
TO 'remoteAdminUser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'dbPass';
```

and then you can use this java code

```
/******************************************************/
//Database Properties
/******************************************************/
String dbName = “dbName”;
String dbUser = “remoteAdminUser”;
String dbPass = “dbPass”;
String filePath = “c:\\sqlDump\myFirstDump.sql”;
/***********************************************************/
// Execute Shell Command
/***********************************************************/
String executeCmd = "";
executeCmd = "mysqldump -u "+dbUser + " -p"+dbPass + " "+dbName + " -r "+filePath;
}
Process runtimeProcess =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
if(processComplete == 0){
out.println("Backup taken successfully");
} else {
out.println("Could not take mysql backup");
}
```

Comment: No, i am trying to dump it from a webserver, which means the MySQL server is on a domain.

Comment: Ok, but let me know if you can query that database from the webServer, for example, can you do a "select * from  information_schema.tables"

Comment: So it means you must have MySQL installed in your local machine to use `mysqldump`, it is also not the best way, is there or not  the to dump the database directly from Java using some protocols?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done if you have access to the server. You can tell `mysqldump` to connect to a remote server:

```
mysqldump -h yourServerAddress -u yourUser -pYourPassword dbName > output_file.sql
```

`yourServerAddress` is the IP address where the MySQL server is.